# check input file type for images

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if in my multiple input field, the images are really images, or not. The problem is, my code still allows to upload pdf, and other files aswell. I read questions here about it, but couldn't this is the only thing I've found, but I don't really understand how else I should use it. This is how it looks like:

```
$selectid = $conn->prepare("SELECT max(id) AS id FROM cards");
$selectid->execute();
$cardid = $selectid->get_result()->fetch_array()['id'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cardimages(image, cardid) VALUES(?, ?)");

$target_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
}
if (count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) > 5) {
    header("Location: addbusiness.php?message=3");
} else {
    $everyPicUnder2Mb = true;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); $i++) {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] > 2100000) {
            $everyPicUnder2Mb = false;
        }
    }


    if ($everyPicUnder2Mb) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); $i++) {
            $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
            if (is_uploaded_file($file)) {
                $imgData = file_get_contents($file);
                $stmt->bind_param("si", $imgData, $cardid);
                $stmt->execute();
            }
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: addbusiness.php?message=2");
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here's my code now. The problem with this is it always gets a '.temp' file so it always thinks it's not an image.

```
    if ($everyPicUnder2Mb) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); $i++) {
            $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];

            $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); #get current file's extension

            if ($imageFileType !== "jpg" && $imageFileType !== "png" && $imageFileType !== "jpeg" && $imageFileType !== "gif") {
                echo 'HIBA! A következő fájl: ' . $file . ' nem JPG, PNG, JPEG vagy GIF formátum.';
                exit;
            }
            if (is_uploaded_file($file)) {
                $imgData = file_get_contents($file);
                $stmt->bind_param("si", $imgData, $cardid);
                $stmt->execute();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: File extensions aren't good enough for this. Use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

Comment: What does `echo $imageFileType;` give?

Comment: This is what it gives: ```Warning: pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given``` and @JayBlanchard could you show that in my code please? Couldn't figure out, how to use it.

Comment: What does `echo $target_file;` return?

Comment: ```Notice: Array to string conversion```

Comment: My bad do a `print_r($target_file);` not echo

Comment: it gives this: ```Array ( [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpE266.tmp )```

Comment: `<input type="file">` has an attribute `accept` which you could use clientside to restrict the fietypes allowed to upload. `<input type="file" name="imagefile" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">`. You could use this _in addition_ to your server side checks

Comment: How can I use that in server side?

Comment: You could use the exif-imagetype function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php This function reads the first dew bytes of the file and checks which type it really is.

Comment: Thank you @Max K That was the solution. I'm gonna post how I exactly did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @MaxK's answer I could solve the problem. Here's how I did it:

```
$allowed_types = array (IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_GIF);
$detectedType = exif_imagetype($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i]);

if (!in_array($detectedType, $allowed_types))
         {
            echo 'Only JPG/JPEG/PNG/GIF';
        }
```